# Can rsync compress only large files during a transfer?

Tags: rsync

Rsync can be slow to transfer small files when the option `-z` is enabled.

Consider a situation with thousands of very small files and a few very big files.

Is there a way to tell rsync to only compress the big files (a threshold in MiB)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely not that rsync is slow at compressing small files (I doubt that is correct) - rather the issue is likely the network latency and network back-and-forth to transmit multiple small files.

Comment: Right I noticed that it was slow for a lot of files but it might not be because of the compression. Like you said, it's very likely due to the network back-and-forth to transmit multiple small files.